# Group by number of results

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table, that has

- ID
- DateTime

I would like to have a result set, which is groupped by 2000 element, displaying the fist DateTime and the last DateTime in each group. Ordered by DateTime. Like:

```
From                 To                   NumberofElements
2012.01.01 00:00:00  2012.02.04 00:00:12  2000
2012.02.04 00:00:43  2012.05.02 01:01:40  140 (because this is the end of the data)
```

There are 2000 elements in each date range.
The eventID is auto-incrementing, but NOT in synchron with the DateTime. Ordering by DateTime is a must.

I have implemented this in PHP, with looping through the entire table, but it would be better to make this in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `ID`, `DateTime` FROM `table` WHERE 1 ORDER BY `votes` DESC LIMIT 0 , 2000
```

If I understood the question correctly